# Why Apache Busy Workers never go back to Idle mode?

Tags: apache-2.4, php-fpm, ab

I have a CentOS 8 server, Apache 2.4, PHP 7.2, 4GB RAM and 2 Core CPUs that is not live yet.

I'm using Apache MPM event and PHP-FPM static and my apache benchmark test shows server can handle 300 concurrent connections for my simple PHP application and I'm okay with it.

The problem is that after I run apache benchmark test of 500 concurrent connections, Apache status shows Busy Workers that never become Idle again unless I restart Apache.

I run apache status 24 hours later and I get the same Idle / Busy Workers. My server is not live yet so the only traffic is my old apache benchmark test.

```
Status: "Total requests: 601; Idle/Busy workers 40/60;Requests/sec: 0.0037; Bytes served/sec: 106 B/sec"
```

Why Apache Busy Workers never go back to Idle mode unless I restart Apache?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apache permanent Busy Workers after Apache Benchmark test](https://serverfault.com/questions/1022393/apache-permanent-busy-workers-after-apache-benchmark-test)

Comment: You already posted this question. Reposting is not allowed here.

Comment: I thought my old question was too long that is why no one answered it, I deleted my old question.

Comment: You should _add_ details to your question, not remove them. There is no such thing as "too long" provided it is relevant.